# loadVariables trace URL

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, legacy

I have a legacy flash app in actionscript 2, that uses a way of communicating with it's server that I am unfamiliar with.

It uses the loadVariables() method, which is a global function in Action Script 2. The legacy code is working as intended, but it needs to be ported and I can't figure out what exactly it is sending.

```
_root.RemoteHost = "http://www.myserver.com/servlet";
_root.CMD = "INIT";
loadVariables(_root.RemoteHost, _root.data, "POST");
```

This makes flash generate and execute a HTTP request along the lines of:

```
http://www.myserver.com/servlet<magic>?CMD=INIT
```

What is the magic portion generated by flash? I cannot find a way to get the URL it generated as a string. Is there a way to find out what it is sending?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you speaking about `sendAndLoad` instead of `loadVariables` ? And who told your that your URL should be `http://www.myserver.com/servlet<magic>?CMD=INIT` ?

Comment: The code uses the `loadVariables` method, but it is definitely sending data from _root as well.
I've tried replacing `loadVariables` with `sendAndLoad` in the legacy flash code, to see if they where synonymous but that does not get a response from the servlet.

The actual url does not contain `<magic>` I was using that as an indicator of the unknown part of the generated url. I know that when I contact the server from the HTML5 app, using the parts of the URL I know to exist are returning a 'not enough information' message. But the URL that flash generates does get the correct response.

Comment: If I understood the situation, your HTML5 app didn't work contrarily of your flash one, that's why you want to get the URL used by flash to contact your server ?

Comment: Yes, both flash and HTML5 are sending a HTTP:POST request to the server. So it is a known URL + some appended variables. The appended variables sent by flash are correct, the ones sent by HTML5 are not. I just want to see what flash is sending as a string so I can compare. But the request is generated by `loadVariables` somehow and I can't see what is in it.

Comment: To capture the request sent by your flash, you can use a capturing network traffic tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and you will see the exact data exchanged between you script and server.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to create a workaround, that gets the intended result from the servlet.
Because I know that the servlet will safely ignore any data it is not looking for, I made Flash trace every possible variable being added to the URL and included all of them in the HTML5 application.

```
trace("<form action=\"" + _global.g_sRemoteHost + "\"  method=\"POST\">");
trace("<fieldset>");
for(var id:String in _root ) 
{
    var value:Object = _root[id];
    if( typeof(value)!= "function" && typeof(value)!= "movieclip" && typeof(value)!= "object")
        trace( "<input type=\"text\" name=\"" + id + "\" value=\"" + value + "\">");
}
trace( "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">" );
trace( "</fieldset>" );
trace( "</form>" );
```

This is a terrible solution, but I hope it will help clarify my question.